# Why does using Passbook with the App Store result in a connection error?

Tags: ios-appstore, ios

I upgraded my iPhone 4S to iOS 6.0. Every time I open Passbook, then touch the 'App Store' button, the App Store app is opened, but then I see the error "Cannot connect to iTunes Store". The App Store app works fine for other purposes if I open it from the home screen.

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error? If it's relevant, I'm in the UK.

Comment: There are probably no Passbook apps for UK.

Comment: I also get the same ‘Cannot connect to the iTunes Store’ notification when opening the App Store from Passbook. I’m in the U.S. Very frustrating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, OK, I think I found a resolution. It's still not quite clear why this works or why there is a problem, but:

> 1. First, head to the Settings in your iPhone.
> 2. Click on General.
> 3. Next, head to Date and Time which is down the list.
> 4. Once you’re in there, you’ll want to change Set Automatically to Off.
> 5. Go to Set Date & Time.
> 6. Click on Today’s Date. Once you do that, you’ll be given the option to change the date.
> 7. Move the year one year forward to 2013.
> 8. This will prevent the error from happening. If you wish to change the date back to the real date, simply set Set Automatically to On and
>      everything will return to normal.
> 9. Head into Passbook and marvel at the apps.

([source](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/09/19/how-to-fix-passbook-error-in-ios-6/))

That fixes the issue on my phone.